# Using QEMU as external translator library

Tags: c, arm, simulation, qemu, cortex-m

I'm expanding circuit emulation engine for Win32 and want to add arm core support and integrate with systemC.
I need some library that allows me to load binary file and execute it step by step. It shouldn't use any kernel drivers or hypervisor.
The execution speed doesn't matter as it mostly will run step by step.
back in the days there was a libqemu that allowed it. Moreover GDB support made it even better. But now it looks like it can work only as standalone emulator. 
May be there are better way? I hope I posted it in the right forum

Comment: Are you just looking for GDB support in QEMU? That's actually available - I can post instructions in the answer section if so.  If you're looking to extend QEMU, though - welcome to the club haha.  Modifying the code is messy at best and a nightmare at worst - there's not a whole lot of documentation.  Your best bet would be to start reading through the source code (I can also provide a basic flow of how things work in the answers if you'd like) and the qemu-devel mailing list.

Comment: I need to control QEMU execution step-by-step from inside my DLL. I want start, load code, execute when I want it step by step. Extract/view memory, registers etc. My code is written in C and Lua. Also I wanted to add support of old CPUs but now I just want to use it as extension for my DLL. Not as standalone executable.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm trying to do with QEMU for Linux.  The short answer is that there's not an easy way to do it - QEMU is not designed to work like that. An easier solution (or at least the best one I have off the top of my head) is to create a gdb-server in your program and use that to interact with QEMU's gdb stub.  I'm not 100% sure how you would start gdb within your application/DLL, but that's going to be a heck of a lot easier than modifying QEMU's source code.

Comment: post it as answer. And thank you a lot for the idea. I will investigate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at : https://hiventive.com

We're developing an open source solution that allow you to connect QEMU with SystemC exporting QEMU CPUs as a library with a TLM-2.0 like interface. A GDB server is also available.

There is a Raspberry Pi demo platform available through our beta.